# Select root folder in SANKYO ICT3K5-3R6940 card reader

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, cardreader

I have a project with this type of card reader. There is a testing tool (RS8Test.exe). I can connect to card reader, retrieve card, reject and manipulate with leds. Bu cannot read any data. Smart card is chip based. I found that there are some commands called IC CARD CONTROL. I can activate IC Card, but cannot execute eny command.
For example how can I get the root folder in the smart card with Sankyo card reader?

```
File Id = 0x00003F00
Command: 00A40000023F00
```

I tried some combinations

```
CI300A40000023F00
C00A40000023F00
CI3A40000023F00
CI300A400023F00
CI300A400003F0002
```

No success.

Maybe someone worked with this card reader.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand: what do you mean by "CI3"? Anyway the problem lies much more probably on the card side, which might be a simple memory card or have no MF at all (e.g. JavaCard). Of course you also should try another rerader. But if you succeed to activate the card, do you get an ATR and how does it look like?

Comment: thanks @guidot for reply. "CI3" is from SANKYO documentation. I can get, select and update data from smart card with any pc/sc usb card reader. But there are some differences with Sankyo, Thats's why I cannot execute anything. I got file id and full command from card manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem and want to add an answer to this question, maybe someone will need a help too.

SANKYO ICT3K5 works with magnet stripe and chip based cards. For chip based cards you must activate IC Card functionality at first, then you can send commands to IC Card. RS8Test.exe testing tool receives commands in hex format. For example for File Id = 0x00003F00, Command: 00A40000023F00 you must follow these steps using RS8Test.exe:

1. Select COM port and Connect to Card reader
2. Send card receive command to ICRW: C20
3. Enter card
4. Activate IC Card: CI0
5. Send file selection command: CI3$00$A4$00$00$02$3F$00
6. If file exists you will R-APDU 9000

$ symbols here are required, if you are using RS8Test.exe and you must include this symbol before each hex data in all you commands.